# How to animate uiscrollview scroll, with customized velocity, while calling the scrollviewdidscroll delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview

Obviously there’s `setContentOffset(animated)` but this is way too slow, as the animation needs to be triggered by a swipe motion, similar to a `pageviewcontroller`. Because of that, there is an ugly delay from fast swipe to slow animation since I can’t change the animation speed of that function.

I tried `UIView.animate` and `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, trying to animate either the bounds or the content offset but nothing worked. The animation needs to be interruptible by another swipe, so `uiview.animate` couldn’t work, and `uiviewpropertyanimator` wouldn’t call scrollview delegate methods which I need to update other graphics.

The only thing that sort of works is a timer, set very fast but it’s stuttery and I know it’s not ideal to use a timer for animation.

Is there any way of animating a uiscrollview, interruptible, while calling scrollviewdidscroll along the way, with adjustable speed?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question since the view already performed some scrolling (after all, `scrollViewDidScroll` was called) but you want to animate scrolling on top of that?

Comment: I want to animate the view, with that delegate method being called along the way. (The animation should tigger the delegate)

Comment: 1- Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer. 2- Don't attempt at animating during the panGesture, simply move the contentOffset to the new position, with iOS's refresh rate, nobody can tell and all system views do this. 3- If you want to do inertia panning on finger lift, use UIKit Dynamics to animate. 4- Call the scrollView delegate method during your pan gesture.